How to Retrieve All Active Subscribers in Child Business Unit with BU-Level Unsubscribes in SFMC?
I need to send an email to all subscribers who are currently subscribed in a specific Child Business Unit.
Our account is configured with "Subscribers will be unsubscribed from this business unit only" enabled. When I query the _Subscribers data view, it returns records from the Parent BU, and since unsubscribes are only tracked at the Child BU level, the Parent BU doesn't reflect any unsubscribes.
As a result, using the ent._Subscribers data view doesn't provide accurate subscription statuses for subscribers in the Child BU.
What is the recommended approach to retrieve all active subscribers in the current Child BU, respecting the BU-level unsubscribe statuses?
I thought about performing a tracking extract of all subscribers and then importing them into a new list, but this doesn't seem efficient and doesn't account for data from other Child BUs.
_ListSubscribers also hasn't provided the correct BU-level subscription statuses.
I'm looking for an efficient and scalable solution without complex workarounds.
Any guidance or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

The BusinessUnitUnsubscribes Data View was retrofitted some years ago for this specific purpose.
ENT._Subscribers is an aggregate list that could never technically support a "1 person has n statuses at the same time", making this a mess to machine-read for a while,
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_businessunitunsubscribes.htm&language=en_US&type=5
You can just query it by your BU's MID given the setting for that BU is "Subscribers will be unsubscribed from this business unit only", which you describe.
You can notice the retrofitting, e.g. it has dates in UTC whereas all "classic" data views have UTC-6 timestamps.
A notable difference to the "event" style data views like _unsubscribe (every unsubscription event -> one row) is that it is a "status" style table. (if someone is currently unsubcribed for a BU, then they appear here, else they don't).

But when I query _Subscribers to retrieve all subscribers in my sfmc I retrieve subscribers from all BUs. Then when I use this BusinessUnitUnsubscribes it gives me only information about unsubs on the current BU (where I use the query), but it doesn't filter out unsubs from other BUs.
Let's say I have 10 subs on BU1 and 15 subs on BU2. I use _Subscribers to retrieve all the subscribers for the current business unit. Then I use the BusinessUnitUnsubscribes , so it will give a correct info about those 10 subs on BU1 but not for the 15 subs on BU2 (who were also retrieved by _Subscribers)

BusinessUnitUnsubscribes doesn't reveal held and bounced.

Held and Bounced are still in ent_subscribers, as this status is global, unlike "unsub by this BU only". An email  address either bounces or does not. it would be counterproductive to split that up.
Your other question - not sure I understand it. But the documentation states you should query the BUUnsubscribes from Parent. You should be seeing info across all BUs.

Thanks! I want to query all active subscribers from all business unit in one specific child BU but with their unsub status. So if I make the query in BU1 and thanks to _Subscribers I retrieve all subscribers across all BUs I would like to know if they are unsubscribed in current or other BU. Is it possible?

Documentation says, you should query BUUnsubscribes from Parent. So just from that viewpoint- the short answer is no. But you can do it in parent, and share the result to child.

Thanks! So If i want to query all active subscribers for a specific BU. Can I do it on parent and then share to child? If so, how is it possible?

Subscribers are never "in a specific BU" on ENT.Subscribers. It is an Enterprise level entity. There is no such notion in the database. The table would also be unsuitable, as one person could plausibly be associated to MANY BUs at the same time, so it would require at least a second table to support a 1:n relationship. Meaning- that is a question you have to ask yourself, it depends on how you split your data into BUs.

Thank you Jonas! Could you also please tell me if I use the _Subscribers data view in child BU1, it will pull subscribers from all BUs. If a person exists in child BU2 and is unsubscribed, but they do not exist in child BU1, will the send (marketing email) still go through because child BU1 won’t recognize they are unsubscribed in child BU2? I think it should recognize, because All Subscribers is a shared list across BUs, right?

We should really stop this chatting.
Last reply: All Subscribers is just a (very very bad) VIEW on what's going on in the backend. It's not even its own table, it is a summary that pulls data from multiple tables  (_unsubscribe, _subscribers, _bounce...) and shows you, human user, what it thinks is correct, based on where you are logged in (== your context).
Sendouts in child BU "know their context" and work accordingly. They automatically respect the setting made in BU settings; the system is just terrible at showing this to you, the user.

The ent. prefix before _Subscribers, means SFMC will check Parent BU information.
If you want to see child-BU level data, you can drop that prefix and simply query FROM _Subscribers.
You can then aggregate all this information into the Parent BU by storing the results of your query into a Shared folder that the parent can query (including the BU of course, so you can know where each subscriber-status pair is coming from).
Hope that helps!
